# NoMethodError in Spree::Api::V2::Storefront::CheckoutController#complete how to solve this in spree 4.6 storefront api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, spree, storefront

I was using 4.40  spree and recently updated it to 4.6 and updated it accordingly but the issue regarding checkout API is still there attaching error image below. Thank you in advance.
[image: error(1)]
[image: error(2)]

Comment: Have you tried with the Spree::Api::V2::Storefront::OrdersController#place method instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was related to the web hooks.
I just included the

```
Spree::Webhooks::HasWebhooks
```

to overridden `order.rb` and the issue got resolved